# What is the effects of adding “Listen 443” to “sshd_config”

Tags: openssh

I was following this tutorial [tutorial](https://www.verot.net/socks.htm) where i added this line
`Listen 443` to `sshd_config` without changing anything else,
now i can no longer connect to the default 22 port

Answer (score 1):

Adding `Listen 443` into `sshd_config` and restarting `sshd` service makes the service fail, because there is no such configuration option recognized by OpenSSH. For more information about configuration options, refer to the manual page for [`sshd_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html).

To be constructive, the correct option should be `Port 443` instead.

Comment: `Listen 443` looks like it has just been copied from an Apache or NCSA httpd configuration without any checking.